# Python: Function to determine if number is square, cube, etc

Tags: python, algorithm, function, math, division

My simple problem is to create a function that determines if a number N can be written as `a^n` for some given n, i.e. I need to check if `N^(1/n)` is a whole number. Somehow this function yields wrong results:

```
def is_power(N, n):
    r = float(N) ** ( 1. / float(n) )
    return r.is_integer()
```

For `n=2` it works.

For `n=3` and N=1,8,27 the function yields True, which is correct. But from then on False, e.g. for `4*4*4=64` or `5*5*5=125`. How can I create a working function that finds numbers that are squares/cubes/etc.?

Comment: Floating point arithmetic is inexact.

Comment: Thank you. How can I create a function that does not fail due to floating point arithmetic issues?

Comment: Would either of http://mpmath.org/ or http://pythonhosted.org/bigfloat/ be helpful?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Floating point arithmetic is not exact--see [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken).

So check your answer using exact-integer math. Round `r` to the nearest integer then see if the power works. This Python 3 code removes some of your redundant type-casting. For Python 2, wrap the calculation of `r` into an `int()` typecast (which is not needed for Python 3).

```
def is_power(N, n):
    r = round(N ** (1.0 / n))
    return r**n == N
```